# Spring Boot 3 JSP Issue

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jsp, dependencies, jakarta-migration

I've been having issues with JSP since moving to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3. I know that we need to use `jakarta.*` instead of `javax.*`, but is there something I'm missing? I am using Spring Tools 4 and just running a basic web app using JSP. When using the following dependencies

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

The project runs, but I get the following error

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet", determined from the Dynamic Web Module facet version (2.5), was not found on the Java Build Path
```

I can get rid of it by adding the javax servlet dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

But that goes against using `javax.*` dependencies with Spring Boot 3.

I have read these articles and tried adding the `jakarta.servlet.jsp` dependency with no luck.

https://debugah.com/solved-tomcat10-error-jakarta-servlet-servletexception-class-com-kuang-servlet-helloservlet-is-not-a-servlet-22749/

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/exception-handling/solved-the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build-path-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

All I had to do was go into **Project Properties** and under **Project Faces**, change my **Dynamic Web Module** from **2.5** to **5.0**

The JSTL warning can be suppressed under **Properties->Web->JSP Files->Validation->Custom actions->Other problems with TagExtraInfo class** (Just change from 'Warning' to 'Ignore')

Comment: Could you please share your pom and the directory structure of the project? In my project the jsp is not resolved in any location by view resolver